# 3D surface area of a raster map (considering topography)

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

How can I calculate the 3D surface area (including topography) for an elevation raster map in R, preferably with package `terra`? Something like the `r.surf.area` module of GRASS GIS, or the `surfaceArea` function of the R `sp` package, but (if possible) also accounting for latitude/longitude:

```
library(terra)
library(sp)

r <- terra::rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
terra::expanse(r)  # computes 2D surface area, considering the relationship between longlat degrees and meters across the globe

m <- sp::SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = crds(r), data = data.frame(r))
sp::surfaceArea(m)  # computes 3D area, considering the sloping nature of the surface
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could adjust the area with (multiplier) `1/cos(slope)`. In that case, for a slope of 45° the adjustment would be `sqrt(2)`

```
1/cos(pi/4)
#[1] 1.414214
```

With that you can do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))

area <- cellSize(r)  
slope <- terrain(r, "slope", unit="radians") 
adjarea <- area / cos(slope)
```

I see that in [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.surf.area.html) and [sp](https://github.com/edzer/sp/blob/main/src/surfaceArea.c) another (perhaps better) approach is used. They create triangles between neighboring cell centers and add up the areas. I could implement that in terra as well.